# data is not showing in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am very new in javascipt infact this is my first program.
i have written html javascrpit code to shoow data in dropdown from python django databse but when i run it, it is not showing data my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>CP Project</title>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        Country : <select class="country" onchange="changeCountry(this)">

        </select><br/>
        State : 
        <select class="state" onchange="changeState(this)">

        </select><br/>
        City : 
        <select class="city" onchange="changeCity(this)">

        </select>

        <script>
            var country = document.querySelector(".country");
            var state = document.querySelector(".state");
            var city = document.querySelector(".city");

            var countryList = {};
            var stateList = {};
            var cityList = {};
            // Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8002/data/ ;
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS;

            getCountryList(function(response){
                countryList = response;
                var tempStr = "";
                /*for(var i in response.result){
                    tempStr+="<option value="+i+">"+response.result[i]+"</option>";
                }*/
                for(var i=0;i<response.length; i++){
                    tempStr+="<option value="+response[i].countryId+">"+response[i].country+"</option>";
                }
                country.innerHTML = tempStr;
            });

            function changeCountry(this_){

                getStateList(this_.value, function(response){
                    stateList = response;
                    var tempStr = "";
                    /*for(var i in response.result){
                        tempStr+="<option value="+i+">"+response.result[i]+"</option>";
                    }*/
                    for(var i=0;i<response.length; i++){
                        tempStr+="<option value="+response[i].state_id+">"+response[i].state+"</option>";
                    }
                    http.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8002/data/country/", true);
                    http.send();
                    state.innerHTML = tempStr;
                });
            }

            function changeState(this_){

                getCityList(this_.value, function(response){
                    cityList = response;
                    var tempStr = "";
                    /*for(var i in response.result){
                        tempStr+="<option value="+i+">"+response.result[i]+"</option>";
                    }*/
                    for(var i=0;i<response.length; i++){
                        tempStr+="<option value="+response[i].cityid+">"+response[i].city+"</option>";
                    }
                    city.innerHTML = tempStr;
                });
            }


            function getCountryList(callBackFun){
                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (this.readyState === 4){
                        callBackFun(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
                    }
                };
                http.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8002/data/country/", true);
                http.send();
            }

            function getStateList(countryCode, callBackFun){
                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (this.readyState === 4){
                        callBackFun(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
                    }
                };
                http.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8002/data/state?count_id="+countryCode, true);
                http.send();
            }

            function getCityList(stateCode, callBackFun){
                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (this.readyState === 4){
                        callBackFun(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
                    }
                };
                http.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8002/data/cities/?sta_id="+stateCode, true);
                http.send();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

it is showing two warning

```
1.SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
2.The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

Comment: Shouldn't the line `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS;` be commented?

Comment: when i commented this this throw an error `
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8002/data/country/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: I think `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS;` would cause a javascript error and would cause your getCountryList call not to run. Because the error stops JS in its tracks. The `Access-Control...`  is something that is supposed to be put in the header of the web service at `/data/country` Although I would expect the error to read `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're probably missing a semicolon.

And adding

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

should solve the bottom error.